# Eclipse error: This project needs to migrate WTP metadata

Tags: java, eclipse, eclipse-wtp

We started a Web Project in Eclipse 3.2 a ways back and we've since upgraded to Eclipse 3.4 but now the Project has the error:

"This project needs to migrate WTP metadata"

We've tried right-clicking and doing the "quick-fix" which is in fact to Migrate WTP Metadata. Unfortunately nothing happens and the error remains.

We can delete that error from the Problems and everything works as it should, however, every time we re-import the project from source control, the error re-appears. Any ideas on how to permanently get rid of this error or how to ACTUALLY migrate WTP metadata?

**UPDATE:** Everyone, please vote on the answer that works for you rather than adding your own answer that references a previous person's answer.

Comment: I had this same problem last week and could not find any resolution :(

Comment: I just updated my answer to reflect yours.

Comment: Removing the .markers file helped me in resolving the issue.

Thanks

Comment: I didn't need WTP so I removed all references to WTP in the .project file.

Answer (score 127, accepted):

The above solution works fine but it creeps up again and again. An easier solution is to right click on the concerned project in Eclipse and choose Validate.

Comment: I have no idea what "Validate" does or why it worked, but that's the only method that really worked. Thanks!

Comment: That doesn't FIX it.  Next time the project is checked out from source control the "This project needs to migrate WTP metadata" error appears again...

Comment: I use this solution as well, but I wish I could get rid of the error permanently!

Comment: didn't work for me came right back after restarting workspace

Answer (score 25):

For me, none of these worked.
The solution for me was deleting the following file while Eclipse was stopped:

```
/workspace/.metadata/.plugins/org.eclipse.core.resources/.projects/myprojectname/.markers
```

Comment: +1. Adding additional search terms for the IBM users out there.  This solution worked for me with IBM Rational Application Developer (RAD) 7.5.5 (7.5.5.1) which, of course, is based on eclipse 3.4.x.

Answer (score 8):

Here is another thing you could try, only this worked for me :(

Go to project properties > Project facets > there tick "Java" and "Utility Module" ... apply
This works if your project is referenced from other projects ..otherwise you could play with those options ...see which one works for you.

Answer (score 4):

try adding this line in the `.project` file

```
<nature>org.eclipse.wst.common.project.facet.core.nature</nature>
```

Or refer to [this discussion](http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/forums/thread.jspa?threadID=141106): for instance, make sure there is no duplicate entries in `.sessions/org.eclipse.wst.common.component`

---

As noted in the comment by [larf311](https://stackoverflow.com/users/31169/larf311), the actual answer in this instance was:

> delete the "`.settings/org.eclipse.wst.common.component`" file.

Simple. ;)

Comment: Hey, if you change your answer to "delete the .settings/org.eclipse.wst.common.component" i'll choose your answer as the solution. You were close.

Answer (score 2):

Removing the .markers file resolved this issue for me.  I would upvote that solution, except that I don't have the "reputation" to do so. :(

Answer (score 2):

This just means that the project configuration of wtp are old, or there's a conflict between modules. go to Projct ->properties -> project facets. Then click the following: dynamic web project ver 2.5, java 5 or 6 and javascript toolkit (not sure if its necessary). You will notice that there have been changes to .settings file. check in the new changes, and everytime someone checks out the project it should be okay

Answer (score 0):

Delete the project, and check it out of source control

Comment: That doesn't help...  We have a project that does it each and every time it is checked out of source control.

Answer (score 0):

I use SVN and every time I checkout the project in a new computer I have this problem, the way I fixed is to copy the .settings from the original location to the new folder of the project, of course use validation

Answer (score 0):

Use maven ... mvn eclipse:clean ... mvn eclipse:eclipse ... reimport the project

Answer (score 0):

In the Properties for the project I selected Project Facets.  None were selected, but there was a message on the right hand side indicating that Java 1.3 or later needed to be selected.  I selected Java 6 and then after closing the Properties window I still had to do a "Validate".  The problem finally disappeared.